# MATLAB dlmwrite function is reordering values when NaNs are involved

Tags: matlab

I have 2 lines to be read in MATLAB

```
200.0  12450  -52.1    NaN    NaN    NaN    205     30  350.1    NaN  350.1
100.0  16630  -79.5    NaN    NaN    NaN    235      8  373.9    NaN  373.9
```

When I print these lines in another file, it returns:

```
200 12450   -52.1   205 30  350.1   350.1   NaN NaN NaN NaN
100 16630   -79.5   235 8   373.9   373.9   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

i.e:
- values in the column 7, 8, 9 and 11 go to columns 4,5,6 and 7;
- NaN's occupy columns 8, 9, 10 and 11 in created file;

How can that issue solved?

Note: I'm using the following command:

```
                dlmwrite(file, niv_padrao, '\t')
```

Comment: Can you post the code for how you assign niv_padrao? For me just writing the array to a file works fine...

Comment: @lhcgeneva Actually, I did a mistake. GIGO. I have corrected the original file. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a matrix like yours:

```
A = [200.0  12450  -52.1    NaN    NaN    NaN    205     30  350.1    NaN  350.1;
     100.0  16630  -79.5    NaN    NaN    NaN    235      8  373.9    NaN  373.9]
```

you could just save it like that:

```
save([pwd '\outputfilename.txt'], 'A','-ASCII');
```

gives you exactly what you want.

Comment: see comments above :P